# PHP serialize() for input form elements?

Tags: php, forms, serialization, hidden

Quick and easy question for those who know it -

I'm using serialize to place an array into a hidden form element - but the quotes (and possibly other characters?) are messing up the html.

Is there a best practice for serialized data passing in html?

Here is the output now:

```
<input type="hidden" value="a:2:{s:8:"buyer_id";i:1;s:11:"buyer_email";s:27:"name@someaddress.com";}" name="custom" />
```

Was thinking of doing an escape-characters function of some sort,but maybe there is something more specialized?

Comment: You are looking for [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities).

Comment: @mario Would not `htmlspecialchars()` suffice? With the `ENT_QUOTES` option of course.

Comment: Wow,that was fast! I replied too soon. Yes - I'll use those.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a more specialized/intelligent way to do this, here is what I will use:

```
$paypal_vars = array(   
    'buyer_id' => $this->user->ID,
    'buyer_email' => $this->user->user_email,   
);

$paypal_vars = htmlspecialchars(serialize($paypal_vars));
```

or

```
$paypal_vars = array(   
    'buyer_id' => $this->user->ID,
    'buyer_email' => $this->user->user_email,   
);

$paypal_vars = htmlentities(serialize($paypal_vars));
```

Comment: Do not forget `ENT_QUOTES`, otherwise `'` can still mess up the HTML.

Comment: you do not need to use `ENT_QUOTES` so long as your HTML uses double quotes around attribute values.